# SQL Query needs revision

Tags: sql, summary

I have the following query :

```
With Summary as (
Select a.ASSN As Association
      ,SUM(tonnage_adjusted) as TotalTonnage
      ,SUM(case when remarks = '' THEN tonnage_adjusted ELSE NULL END) as Monitored
      ,SUM(case when remarks = 'NO_TICKET' THEN tonnage_adjusted ELSE NULL END) as NotMonitored
From DeliveryTons d INNER JOIN FarmerGroups a ON d.reaping_code = a.REAPING_GROUP_CODE 
WHERE reaping_code IS NOT NULL AND d.crop_season = 4 
Group By a.ASSN
)

SELECT Association
  ,TotalTonnage
  , COALESCE(Monitored,0) As Monitored
  , COALESCE(NotMonitored,0)As NotMonitored
  , COALESCE(((Monitored/TotalTonnage) * 100),0) as pct_Monitored
FROM Summary 
Order by Association,TotalTonnage
```

And following table examples:

DeliveryTons

```
id | parcel_id | crop_season | tonnage_adjusted | reaping_code | remarks 
1    012-0075       4               25.60            NSCGA12     
2    011-0089       3               17.58            PSCPA      NO_TICKET 
3    001-0541       3               14.58            PSCPA       
4                   2               18.50            NSCGA12    NO_TICKER
```

FarmerGroups

```
ID | ASSN  |   REAPING_GROUP_CODE  |  CROP_SEASON
1    CSCPA        NSCGA12                  4
2    PSCPA        PSCPA                    3
3    PSCPA        NSCGA12                  4
```

I want to get the tonnage_adjusted totals by association, however I seem to be getting higher sums of tonnage_adjusted than are actually there by crop_season. Almost as pulling data from other crop_seasons. Can anyone see if there is anything wrong with the sql?

Comment: You probably need to add `AND d.crop_season = a.crop_season` to your `JOIN` condition

Comment: Doing that gives me even bigger sums

Comment: That seems strange as adding that condition should restrict the number of rows further, not increase them. Unfortunately you haven't supplied sufficient sample data to reproduce the problem, if you could edit the question with more data so that the problem can be reproduced it would make it easier to answer.

Comment: @Kaii Sorry that would not result in more rows

Comment: What is your expected output for the given example?

Comment: @kaii. Your last code did seem to do the trick. Except i had to use another column data.

Comment: @ivias just for completeness / for others looking for help here:   what columns did you use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the join pulls more than 1 matching row from the FarmGroups table, resulting in a cross product.

I guess that it should not, but now you have multiple entries for the same ReapingCode/Season combination.

Maybe you want to cleanup your data and add an `UNIQUE KEY(REAPING_GROUP_CODE, CROP_SEASON)` to avoid such duplications in the future. If I understand correctly, a single REAPING_GROUP_CODE in a specific SEASON can only be accounted to one ASSN.

If thats not possible, you can still do this to eliminate the duplicate on query time, but it will not perform as good as a cleanup + schema change:

```
With Summary as (
Select a.ASSN As Association
      ,SUM(tonnage_adjusted) as TotalTonnage
      ,SUM(case when remarks = '' THEN tonnage_adjusted ELSE NULL END) as Monitored
      ,SUM(case when remarks = 'NO_TICKET' THEN tonnage_adjusted ELSE NULL END) as NotMonitored
FROM DeliveryTons d 
    /* NOTE the SELECT DISTINCT subquery here */
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         ASSN,REAPING_CODE_GROUP,CROP_SEASON FROM FarmerGroups 
         WHERE CROP_SEASON = 4
    ) a 
    ON d.reaping_code = a.REAPING_GROUP_CODE 
    AND d.crop_season = a.CROP_SEASON
WHERE reaping_code IS NOT NULL 
Group By a.ASSN
)

SELECT Association
  ,TotalTonnage
  , COALESCE(Monitored,0) As Monitored
  , COALESCE(NotMonitored,0)As NotMonitored
  , COALESCE(((Monitored/TotalTonnage) * 100),0) as pct_Monitored
FROM Summary 
Order by Association,TotalTonnage
```